# Web Fragment project setting in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am working on J2EE project with Struts 2. I am going to divide different module through web fragment project.

In my core module I am using Struts 2 and it works well. Now I also want my fragment module to use Struts 2.

So is it a good practice to place all the mapping in `struts.xml` of core module?

Is it possible to divide the `struts.xml` into pieces and place in different fragment module?

If I can place `struts.xml` in fragment module, which folder should I place it ?

Answer (score 0):

All module development are done with the concept of namespaces. You could create different modules under different namespaces. To separate the modules configuration files you should use `include` tag. Place the module config into the corresponding file and put it in the `struts.xml`:

```xml
<include file="struts-module1.xml"/>
<include file="struts-module2.xml"/>
...
```

If you need the understanding the namespaces in the struts2 then look at [Struts 2 Namespace configuration example and explanation](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-namespace-configuration-example-and-explanation/).