# There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [home] associated with context path [/struts]

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, struts2, http-status-code-404

Hope someone just could give a hint where to look for the source of the problem.

**Class Login Action**

```
@Namespace("/")
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
@Action(value = "/welcome", results = { @Result(name = SUCCESS, location =  "/WEB-INF/content/welcome.jsp") })

When I exectute my index.jsp to execute welcome.jsp didn't work.
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Welcome to Struts 2</h3>
<s:form action="home">
    <s:textfield name="username" label="User Name"></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield name="password" label="Password" type="password">       </s:textfield>
    <s:submit value="Login"></s:submit>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
enter code here

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=IUTF-8">
<title>Welcome To Struts 2</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h3>
        Welcome
       <s:property value="username"></s:property>
     !
   </h3>
</body>
```

**Result**
**Struts Problem Report**

Struts has detected an unhandled exception:

**Messages:**

```
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [home] associated with context path [/struts].
```

Comment: Post the code via editing the question, not via the comment. Also the code has a different error rather than on the image. You should clarify the question. I'm sure the source of the problem in the action mapping.

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097002/struts-2-there-is-no-action-mapped-for-namespace ?

Comment: It didn't work yet, sclv. Thank you.

Comment: *There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [home]*.

Comment: @Marcelo Don't read other answers, read my answer instead.

Comment: @RomanC thank you. I found the problem.        

On my index.jsp I named my action = "home", on my LoginAction I named = "welcome" and I put my welcome.jsp in content folder now I put it on Webapp.

Now it works :)

Comment: Thank everyone that tried to help me.

Comment: @Marcelo Post your `index.jsp`.

Comment: @RomanC I posted them.

Comment: @Marcelo Because you already solved the problem then you can post the answer or delete this altogether.

Comment: @RomanC I answered the post.
Could you check it please.
As you can see, I'm new in struts2, if you have a book or site to indicate, I would be glad.

Comment: @Marcelo I've read the post, see my answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36172286/573032).

Comment: Also duplicate of [Struts2 There is no Action mapped for namespace \[/\] and action name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40650763/573032).

Answer (score 0):

In Struts2 you map a form to the action config using `s:form` tag's `action` and `namespace` attributes.

Normally, the action attribute accepts the action name, but it can contain the URL. The form tag is rendered by the template to HTML `form` where the action attribute have to be URL.

So Struts is getting the action name and generate URL. You can see the source code in the browser. When request is made Struts2 uses the request URI to find the action mapping as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21097463/573032).

Usually the 404 error results in missing action configuration on the server that corresponds to the requested URI. When you submitted a form the request is made and resource is requested but the action config is not found, hence Struts2 returns 404 error.

You don't need to use annotations if you are utilizing a convention or rest plugins but the annotation always allows manually override the defaults.

By default the results path is `/WEB-INF/contents/` and the action name is without slashes, so you can use annotation:

```java
@Action(value = "welcome", results = @Result(location = "welcome.jsp") )
```

---

You can find the references to online resources from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27686588/573032) answer.

The one from tutorials [read this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17555145/573032).

Answer (score -1):

**The solution.**

In my index.jsp I wrote "home" in the tag action, form action="home" The correct are the same name at the Action.

```
<html>
    <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
     <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
   <body>
       <h3>Welcome to Struts 2</h3>
       <s:form action="home"> **The correct is "welcome"**
       <s:textfield name="username" label="User Name"></s:textfield>
       <s:textfield name="password" label="Password" type="password">    </s:textfield>
       <s:submit value="Login"></s:submit>
     </s:form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**And in my LoginAction I used  value ="/welcome".**

```
package web.actions;

@Action(value = "/welcome", results = { @Result(name = SUCCESS, location = "/WEB-INF/content/welcome.jsp") })

public String execute() throws Exception {
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

**The messagem is very clear.**
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [home] associated with context path [/struts].

But I just saw the mistake doing a lot of examples.

Comment: Usually on SO the question has wrong code, and the answer contains the right one. But I think you didn't write the correct one even in comments where you state its correctness.

Comment: Also this answer looks like the edit to the question. Please distinguish the answer and the question providing a credit to the author.