# There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [login] associated with context path [/Struts2Test]

Tags: jsp, configuration, struts2, namespaces, action

I'm a beginner of Struts2, I know this question been asked in here much times, but I tried to solve it and read much much threads here, spend 6 hours and still can't get it work. Really need more suggestion...

**Here's my Package:**

```
Struts2Test
  +Struts2Test/src
    +tw.com.rrstudio.java.test
      -TestAction.java
  +Struts2Test/build
  +Struts2Test/WebContent
    +Struts2Test/WebContent/META-INF
      +Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes
      +Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib
      -Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml
      -Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml
      -Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/struts.xml
      -Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/struts2-action.xml
      -Struts2Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml
    -Struts2Test/WebContent/error.jsp
    -Struts2Test/WebContent/index.jsp
    -Struts2Test/WebContent/TestAction.jsp
```

**My `web.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Struts2Test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/spring-context.xml
      /WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
      <param-value>tw.com.rrstudio.java.test</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <jsp-config>
    <taglib>
      <taglib-uri>HTTP://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
      <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/tld/c.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

</web-app>
```

**And also, `struts.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
  <!-- struts 2.3.16.3 has problem of security,needing to set DynamicMethodInvocation=false -->
  <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
  
  <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />

  <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="do"/>
  <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/jsp/.*?,/image/.*?,/css/.*?,/js/.*?,.*\\.jsp"/>

  <package name="default" extends="json-default" ></package>

  <package name="Strut2Test" extends="json-default" >
    <global-results>
      <result name="SystemErrorPage">/WebContent/error.jsp</result>
    </global-results>
    <action name="login" class="tw.com.rrstudio.java.test.TestAction">
      <result name="index">/WebContent/index.jsp</result>
      <result name="success">/WebContent/TestAction.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>

</struts>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=login.action">
<title>Index of Struts2Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Index of Struts2Test</h1>
  <form action="testAction" method="post">
    <label for="name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Say Hello"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Server is Tomcat 8.0.38, it starts with no error. But when I access

- `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Struts2Test/`
- `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Struts2Test/login`

it gives me this(as title) error, and if I access

- `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Struts2Test/index.jsp`

I will get a regular 404 result.

Now I have no idea, any suggestions or tips are welcome...

Comment: Why are you mixing Struts2 with Spring MVC ? Try removing any Spring MVC reference from web.xml, also remove the actionPackages param from struts2 filter, and comment the Spring objectFactory settings. Also note that you need struts2-spring-plugin to use spring as objectFactory, while SpringMVC has nothing to do with it

Comment: Because that's my company did that, it's an exist structure they used for years. I need to try something about bug fix/new feature, all based on this structure.

Comment: Well, your best shot then is to look at the differences between your configuration and (the same part of) the configuration of a working project based on this structure. Look especially into xml struts files (I see you have two, you've posted only one). But before this tedious work, you can still try (add it if not already present) the [**config-browser-plugin**](https://struts.apache.org/docs/config-browser-plugin.html) and look for `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Struts2Test/config-browser/actionNames.action`: it'll tell you exactly what is mapped to what in your whole webapp. Is worthy of a try ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ## Issues related to: There is no Action mapped for namespace and action name associated with context path

If you use URL to call an action, make sure this URL is mapped to the Struts configuration. To troubleshoot the issue with URL mapping you can use [config-browser](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/config-browser/) plugin. Simply add this plugin to your project dependencies and when it's deployed, you can access a website showing you a runtime configuration with available URLs to call the action. For example if you are running Tomcat locally on port 8080 and deployed your application at the `context`, then you can access the plugin's URL with

```
http://localhost:8080/[context]/config-browser/index.action
```

You can click any action available on the actions page under the namespace on the sidebar. Also note that if your action is not found on  the package it might be in the `default` package. Struts does additional search in the `default` namespace for the action that is not at the namespace mapped from the URL.

---

> Check out the [config-browser](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/config-browser/) plugin to debug configuration
> issues.
>
> To map correctly url to the action two parameters are required: the
> action name and namespace.
>
> Struts loads xml configuration on startup and it should know the
> location of the `struts.xml`. By default it's looking on classpath to
> find a file with known name like `struts.xml`. Then it parses document
> and creates a runtime configuration. This configuration is used to
> find appropriate configuration element for the action url. If no such
> element is found during request, the 404 error code is returned with
> the message: `There is no Action mapped for namespace and action name`.
>
> Also this message contains a namespace and action names used to find
> the action config. Then you can check your configuration settings in
> `struts.xml`. Sometimes the action name and namespace, stored in
> [`ActionMapping`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/mapper/ActionMapping.html) point to the wrong action. These values are determined
> by the [`ActionMapper`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/mapper/ActionMapper.html) which could have different implementation, used
> by plugins.
>
> There's also another setting that might affect this mapper and
> mapping, but the point is the same if you get this message then URL is
> used didn't map any action config in runtime configuration. If you
> can't realize which URL you should use, you might try
> [config-browser](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/config-browser/) plugin to see the list of URLs available to use.

---

Comment: It helps me to know my real action path, thank you. Now I have another 404 issue......

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [config-browser plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/config-browser/) to debug configuration issues.

In our set-up we used the link:

```
http://localhost:8080/[context]/config-browser/index.do
```

In our case we found that we had conflicting `struts.xml` files at two different folder levels. By conflicting I mean that the actions inside them overlapped using the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Check struts.xml for constant struts.action.excludePattern and that entry for login is present in that or not. In my case it was exclude pattren which was creating problem.

This is applicable if you are giving servlet call in struts2 based app

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, because the struts.xml file wasn't located in the right place, what is the src folder! ('!' == rookie surprise):

```
ApplicationProjectRoot
|
|__Java Resources
|  |
|  |__src
|  |  |__struts.xml
|  |  |__any.package.app
|  |     |__AnyClass.java
|  |
|  |__Libraries                
 [...]
```