# Deploy Dynamic Web JSP using Struts2 on WebSphere

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts2, websphere-liberty

I have a project dynamic web using struts2 version 2.3.1.2.
I want to deploy this project to WebSphere. But I get trouble is:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[null]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport:
```

**This is my file `web.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_9" 
version="2.4">
<display-name>Struts2 Application</display-name>
<filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>LoginAction</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>net.viralpatel.struts2.action.LaunchServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
</web-app>
```

**This is class `LaunchServlet`:**

```
public class LaunchServlet extends HttpServlet implements Servlet {
public LaunchServlet() {
    super();
}
public void init(ServletConfig arg0) throws ServletException {      
    // this works around a bug in the websphere classloader.
    super.init(arg0);
    Dispatcher d = new Dispatcher(getServletContext(), new HashMap<String, 
String>());        
}
}
```

**This is file `struts.xml`:**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
    value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
    value="ApplicationResources" />

<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="login"
        class="net.viralpatel.struts2.action.LoginAction">
        <result name="success">Welcome.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Don't follow some outdated sites. Take a look at the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use servlet mapping and new Struts filter

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginAction</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginAction</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

then add `excludePattern` constant to `struts.xml` to exclude servlet mapping URL from Struts executing.

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/LoginAction/?.*"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm try it but get an other error:

    Error 404: There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [] associated with context path [/Struts2_Hello_World].

I'm try on tomcat 7. it's working. But websphere it's no working!

Comment: Another error should be posted in another question. But your error is well known and there's an answer that solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/40658006/573032