# Struts2 exclude pattern regular expression issues

Tags: spring, struts2

I have a requirement like if the URL contains spring in the path,then the struts should be excluded and spring dispatcher servlet should be processed.

I have tried the below pattern
constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="*.spring.*"/>

URLS's to be skipped: http://localhost:8080/spring/getAllUsers
http://localhost:8080/spring/getUserByName

But am getting error like No action mapped from struts.Please suggest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jersey with Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293115/jersey-with-struts2)

Comment: `No action mapped` means that struts can't fine the action mapping for request url. More about this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40658006/573032).

Answer (score 0):

Use `.*` which means zero or more characters like:

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value=".*spring.*" />
```

Comment: @Abirami, try `<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value=".*spring.*" />`

Comment: @yaser  I think am trying the same pattern if am not wrong

Comment: @Abirami, your pattern which you posted in your question does not have any `*`. It has `.`. I meant replace with `.*`