# Struts2 Redirect to External URL from Server

Tags: java, servlets, struts2, struts

I have an application that I am trying to redirect to an external URl (https) however my page is not moving to the new URL. The application is firing the URL as a GET request in the browser. See code under;

**Action Class**

```
public String Authorization() {

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost();     

try {

    post.setHeader("Accept", "*/*");    
    post.setHeader("Allow-Origin", "*");
    post.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    post.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");             
    post.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    post.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    post.setHeader("content-type", "text/xml,application/xml");

    jsonData.put("url", loginManager.Authorize());          
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());


} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
}
return Action.SUCCESS;
```

}

**STRUTS.xml**

```
<action name="AuthenticateO365" class="org.myapp.product.controller.LoginAction" method="Authorization">            
<result name="input"></result>
<result name="success" type="redirect">${jsonData.url}</result>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--the `success` result is a redirect to the url in `jsonData`, and you're saying that's what's happening ("the application is firing the URL as a GET request in the browser"). But you also say the opposite. Can you be more clear?

Comment: The page is not moving to the new URL and in the browser console i am seeing the response as the HTML page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48373548/573032