# Struts2 - Best way to redirect to another domain

Tags: redirect, struts2, cross-domain

My website has a section that will be migrated to another domain, but all our clients still use the old url, which will be deprecated soon.

What i want to achieve is send `301 moved permanently` HTTP Response, and send the users to the new domain.

Already tried

sendRedirect

```
ServletActionContext.getResponse().setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
ServletActionContext.getResponse().sendRedirect(urlToNewDomain);
```

and

```
ServletActionContext.getResponse().setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
ServletActionContext.getResponse().setHeader("Location", urlToNewDomain);
ServletActionContext.getResponse().setHeader("Connection", "close");
```

and with struts response (using XML)

```
    <result name="externalRedirect" type="httpheader">
        <param name="status">301</param>
        <param name="headers.location">${targetUrl}</param>
    </result>
```

The response its a 301 like: `myDomain.com/newDomainUrl`

So it keeps using `myDomain.com` ... i don't know how t explicitly redirect to a different domain.

Which is the best way to redirect to a different domain?

Comment: What are you putting in `urlToNewDomain` or `targetUrl`? What is "it" that keeps using `myDomain.com`?

Comment: Redirect to another domain means always leaving your application. What prevents you from using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48373548/573032)?